# SQL join two tables without unique key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This is being done on SQL Server 2005.

I've got 2 separate tables without a unique attribute.

Table A columns: `NAME|FROM|EMAIL`

Table B columns: `NAME|FROM|EMAIL`

I'm trying to get *all results from A* + *all results from B* where the `FROM` equals '123'.

```
SELECT
x.FROM as 'FROM',
x.Email as 'Email',
x.Name as 'Name'
FROM TableA x
INNER JOIN TableB y 
ON x.FROM = y.FROM
WHERE x.FROM = '123'
```

Current SQL script gives bad results, nothing from TableB and only 1 result from TableA in duplicated manner.

Is `Inner Join` wrong join type here?

Comment: You don't select any TableB columns... Try `select * from ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `union all`:

```
select name, [from], email
from a
union all
select name, [from], email
from b
where [from] = '123';
```

You should also upgrade your SQL Server to a supported version.  SQL Server *2008* is losing support in a few months.

Comment: I think there needs to be a where clause after `from a`.

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked perfectly. As Marlin noted, using the WHERE command on TableA is something I added on top.